# The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character

Tags: c#, file-io, base64

I have a REST service that reads a file and sends it to another console application after converting it to Byte array and then to Base64 string. This part works, but when the same stream is received at the application, it gets manipulated and is no longer a valid Base64 string. Some junk characters are getting introduced into the stream.

The exception received when converting the stream back to Byte is

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64
>   character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space
>   character among the padding characters

**At Service:**

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "ReadFile/Convert", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]  
public string ExportToExcel()
  {
      string filetoexport = "D:\\SomeFile.xls";
      byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(filetoexport);
      var s = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
      return s;
  }
```

**At Application:**

```
       var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:56877/User/");
       var request = new RestRequest("ReadFile/Convert", RestSharp.Method.GET);
       request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/Json");
       request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/Json");
       request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => {resp.ContentType =    "application/Json";};
       var result = client.Execute(request);
       byte[] d = Convert.FromBase64String(result.Content);
```

Comment: Probably this has to do with `Encoding`.

Comment: Do you know what "junk characters" are being inserted?

Comment: The updated code is helpful. Now we need to see the string that you send (i.e. `s` on the service) and the content that's received (i.e. `result.content`. You don't need to post the entire string, just up to the first mangled character (or, if that's still too long, some substrings that show what was sent and what was received).

Comment: @JimMischel yeah, i noticed that '/' is getting replaced with '\/'

Comment: @RohitVerma For the slash getting replaced, is that in the raw HTML contents (Fiddler will tell you), or in `result.Content`? That will tell you if the problem is with the server or the client.

Comment: The error could also be related to a padding issue @see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50525594/5102373

Answer (score 160):

Check if your image data contains some header information at the beginning:

```
imageCode = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAABkC...
```

This will cause the above error.

Just remove everything in front of and including the first comma, and you good to go.

```
imageCode = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAABkC...
```

Comment: Had this exact issue somehow. Logic is to remove everything after `,` if `data:` is present. Bam. Working now.

Comment: var cleanerBase64 = imageCode.Substring(22);  // remove data:image/png;base64

Comment: Just a little bit of code to help......


if (this.imageCode.Contains(','))
    this.imageCode = this.imageCode.Substring(this.imageCode.IndexOf(",") + 1, this.imageCode.Length - (this.imageCode.IndexOf(",") + 1));

Comment: I would use: .Split(',')[1]

Comment: `str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(',') + 1)` should do it.

Comment: solved my problem. I was trying to save the base64 string to azure endpoint. After removed the header str, it worked. works like magic, thank you!

Comment: this worked for me as well. I'm wondering if there's any reason why Convert.FromBase64String doesn't handle this scenario

Comment: I came here but had this message but with smtp issue on login. Turns out the office365 user email account was not licensed/mail setup with the right options. So there error for me was a red herring.

Answer (score 96):

Very possibly it's getting converted to a modified Base64, where the `+` and `/` characters are changed to `-` and `_`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history

If that's the case, you need to change it back:

```
string converted = base64String.Replace('-', '+');
converted = converted.Replace('_', '/');
```

Comment: I got this done ....Thanks to you!!
Replacing the characters with the appropriate ones. But is this a concrete solution ? i mean how can i guarantee that for all the files this will be the character to be replaced ?

Comment: @RohitVerma: I don't know. You need to find out where those characters are getting changed, and determine if it's likely to change any other characters. I'm not familiar with RestSharp, so I can't offer any advice there. If my response answered your question, it's customary to mark it as the accepted answer. (Click the checkmark next to the answer on the left.)

Comment: OMG Thank you! This and adding the necessary padding "=" characters solved my problem. The decrypt function in Azure's Key Vault REST API needs this process and doesn't document it.

Answer (score 43):

We can remove unnecessary string input in front of the value.

```
string convert = hdnImage.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", String.Empty);

byte[] image64 = Convert.FromBase64String(convert);
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. But this is specifically for png images. Is there any generalized syntax which replaces all kinds of image extensions?

Comment: i read your comment now. i dont try this but you can use this: hdnImage.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", String.Empty).Replace("data:image/jpg;base64,", String.Empty).Replace("data:image/bmp;base64,", String.Empty); again, i dont try this. please try and write for me. i will change.

Answer (score 17):

Remove the unnecessary string through **Regex**

```
Regex regex=new Regex(@"^[\w/\:.-]+;base64,");
base64File=regex.Replace(base64File,string.Empty);
```

Comment: Most efficient way of removing unnecessary string, Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Since you're returning a string as JSON, that string will include the opening and closing quotes in the raw response. So your response should probably look like:

```
"abc123XYZ=="
```

or whatever...You can try confirming this with Fiddler.

My guess is that the `result.Content` is the raw string, including the quotes. If that's the case, then `result.Content` will need to be deserialized before you can use it.

Comment: you are correct, this includes " " but the point here is that apart from the addition of these quotation marks other characters are also getting replaced.

Comment: Deserializing that string using a JSON serializer will take care of both the quotes and the escaped slash. Escaping your forward slashes with a backslash is something that some JSON serializers do - using a deserializer will turn \/ back into just plain / so that you'll get valid base-64. Since you're receiving JSON, it's always a good idea to parse that JSON properly, even if it is just a simple string.

Answer (score 6):

**Just in case you don't know the type of uploaded image, and you just you need to remove its `base64` header:**

```
 var imageParts = model.ImageAsString.Split(',').ToList<string>();
 //Exclude the header from base64 by taking second element in List.
 byte[] Image = Convert.FromBase64String(imageParts[1]);
```

Comment: split and To List ? use rather IndexOf and substring

Comment: see http://demeranville.com/battle-of-the-tokenizers-delimited-text-parser-performance/ and the question is also posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388181/split-method-vs-substring-and-indexof

Answer (score 6):

Probably the string would be like this `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QN8RXh...`
First split for `/` and get the second token.

```
var StrAfterSlash = Face.Split('/')[1];
```

Then Split for `;` and get the first token which will be the format. In my case it's jpeg.

```
var ImageFormat =StrAfterSlash.Split(';')[0];
```

Then remove the line `data:image/jpeg;base64,` for the collected format

```
CleanFaceData=Face.Replace($"data:image/{ImageFormat };base64,",string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 3):

I arranged a similar context as you described and I faced the same error. I managed to get it working by removing the `"` from the beginning and the end of the content and by replacing  `\/` with `/`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
var result = client.Execute(request);
var response = result.Content
    .Substring(1, result.Content.Length - 2)
    .Replace(@"\/","/");
byte[] d = Convert.FromBase64String(response);
```

As an alternative, you might consider using XML for the response format:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "ReadFile/Convert", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]  
public string ExportToExcel() { //... }
```

On the client side:

```
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/xml"; };

var result = client.Execute(request);
var doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(result.Content);
var xml = doc.InnerText;
byte[] d = Convert.FromBase64String(xml);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var spl = item.Split('/')[1];
var format =spl.Split(';')[0];           
stringconvert=item.Replace($"data:image/{format};base64,",String.Empty);
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Answer (score 3):

please check if there is no == as a postfix,
just add == chars at last of string

```
// "........V/XeAeH/wALVWKtD8lz/AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg"
"........V/XeAeH/wALVWKtD8lz/AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="    /* yes */
```

Answer (score 2):

As [Alex Filipovici](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114044/the-input-is-not-a-valid-base-64-string-as-it-contains-a-non-base-64-character#comment21267678_15114044) mentioned the issue was a wrong encoding. The file I read in was `UTF-8-BOM` and threw the above error on `Convert.FromBase64String()`. Changing to `UTF-8` did work without problems.

Answer (score 1):

And some times it started with double quotes,
most of the times when you call API from dotNetCore 2 for getting file

```
string string64 = string64.Replace(@"""", string.Empty);
byte[] bytes = Convert.ToBase64String(string64);
```

Comment: Cannot convert from string to byte[]

Answer (score 0):

I get this error because a field was **varbinary** in **sqlserver** table instead of **varchar**.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error in my code, it was due to Base64-encoded strings might have been formatted for display or transmission in a way that includes spaces or line breaks.
I fixed it by replacing all space characters in the string with '+' characters.

You can try this if it fits your use case.
Here it the sample code :-

```
byte[] inputtextbyteArray = new byte[ourText.Replace(" ", "+").Length];
//This technique reverses base64 encoding when it is received over the Internet.
inputtextbyteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(ourText.Replace(" ", "+"));
using MemoryStream input = new(inputtextbyteArray);
```