# Split Method vs Substring and IndexOf

Tags: java, parsing, csv

so I'm writing a program that parses a CSV. I'm using the split method to separate the values into a string array, but I've read in some articles that it's faster to use substring and indexOf. I wrote essentially what I would do with those two methods, and it seems like split would be better. Could someone explain how this is better, or if maybe I'm not correctly utilizing these methods?  Here's what I wrote:

```
int indexOne = 0, indexTwo;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) //there's four diff values in one line
{
   if (line.indexOf(",", indexOne) != -1)
   {
       indexTwo = line.indexOf(",", indexOne);
       lineArr[i] = line.substring(indexOne, indexTwo);
       indexOne = indexTwo+1;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you possibly link some of those articles?

Comment: Consider using lodash or underscore or similar to not deal with things like this.

Comment: @AustinD Here's a link http://demeranville.com/battle-of-the-tokenizers-delimited-text-parser-performance/   somebody put it in a comment on stackexchange here's that thread http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/221997/quickest-way-to-split-a-delimited-string-in-java

Comment: @Michael Do you mean in the CSV file?

Comment: Both dealing with CSV and "string-gymnastics" :)

Comment: @Michael Isn't Lodash and underscore JavaScript libraries? This is Java code, not JavaScript.

Comment: @dlcole, you are right, my mistake :) (same answer applies though :))

Comment: @AustinD I'm not surprised that split() would be faster. This is a common operation that has been repeated over and over and when Java finally added it, I would tend to believe they were using an optimized algorithm. That's not always the case, but I tend towards not reinventing the wheel when it has been created for me unless there is concrete evidence that it is inefficient.

Comment: @dlcole thanks for the input, I didn't know how split would scale for larger files, but you make a good point!

Comment: One of the nice things about Java is that the JDK ships with the source code. Taking a peak it looks like in the use case where you're splitting on a single character it is performing logic very similar to what you have here. In the use case that you split on something more complex it uses Pattern.split().

Comment: @Weave So using split wouldn't necessarily be less efficient in this case?

Comment: Worrying about performance at this point is premature optimization. Unless you are going to process tens of millions of records at a time it won't make ANY difference and you'll just waste time doing work you probably don't need to do.  What you should REALLY be doing is using a CSV library instead of reinventing the wheel.  Google "Java CSV parser".  CSV looks simple but there are a few subtle points, such as string quoting and embedded quotes that are tricky to get right.  If you are doing this for the practice, go ahead; for "real" work, use a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is taken from the source shipped with Oracles JDK 8 update 73. As you can see in the "fastpath" scenario when you pass in a one-char String it falls to a loop using indexOf similar to your logic.

The short answer is yes your code is a little faster but I'll leave it to you to decide if that is enough of a benefit to avoid using split in your use case.

Personally I tend to agree with @pczeus comment use split unless you actually have evidence that it is causing an issue.

```
 public String[] split(String regex, int limit) {
    /* fastpath if the regex is a
     (1)one-char String and this character is not one of the
        RegEx's meta characters ".$|()[{^?*+\\", or
     (2)two-char String and the first char is the backslash and
        the second is not the ascii digit or ascii letter.
     */
    char ch = 0;
    if (((regex.value.length == 1 &&
         ".$|()[{^?*+\\".indexOf(ch = regex.charAt(0)) == -1) ||
         (regex.length() == 2 &&
          regex.charAt(0) == '\\' &&
          (((ch = regex.charAt(1))-'0')|('9'-ch)) < 0 &&
          ((ch-'a')|('z'-ch)) < 0 &&
          ((ch-'A')|('Z'-ch)) < 0)) &&
        (ch < Character.MIN_HIGH_SURROGATE ||
         ch > Character.MAX_LOW_SURROGATE))
    {
        int off = 0;
        int next = 0;
        boolean limited = limit > 0;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((next = indexOf(ch, off)) != -1) {
            if (!limited || list.size() < limit - 1) {
                list.add(substring(off, next));
                off = next + 1;
            } else {    // last one
                //assert (list.size() == limit - 1);
                list.add(substring(off, value.length));
                off = value.length;
                break;
            }
        }
        // If no match was found, return this
        if (off == 0)
            return new String[]{this};

        // Add remaining segment
        if (!limited || list.size() < limit)
            list.add(substring(off, value.length));

        // Construct result
        int resultSize = list.size();
        if (limit == 0) {
            while (resultSize > 0 && list.get(resultSize - 1).length() == 0) {
                resultSize--;
            }
        }
        String[] result = new String[resultSize];
        return list.subList(0, resultSize).toArray(result);
    }
    return Pattern.compile(regex).split(this, limit);
}
```

Comment: I see in profiling methos they suggest to use indexOf and substring. Can you shed some light over that?