# c# - base64 jpeg to MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, asp.net, memorystream

I have a base64 jpeg like so: data:image/jpeg;base64 and I am trying to convert it to a MemoryStream so I can upload it to OneDrive....Here is what I got so far:

```
byte[] frontBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(user.FrontLicense);

using (MemoryStream frontMS = new MemoryStream(frontBytes))
{
    await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items[newFolder.Id].ItemWithPath("FrontLicense.jpeg").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(frontMS);
}
```

But I get this error:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64
>   character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character
>   among the padding characters.

On this line:

```
byte[] frontBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(user.FrontLicense);
```

This is what user.FrontLicense looks like:

> data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoM.....

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to remove the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` before base64-decoding it.

Comment: Looks like this might be a duplicate... [check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114044/the-input-is-not-a-valid-base-64-string-as-it-contains-a-non-base-64-character)

Comment: @JEllery: Not a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part at the start - `data:image/jpeg;base64,` - isn't part of the base64 data. So you need to remove that first:

```cs
const string Base64ImagePrefix = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"
...

if (user.FrontLicense.StartsWith(Base64ImagePrefix))
{
    string base64 = user.FromLicense.Substring(Base64ImagePrefix.Length);
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    // Use the data
}
else
{
    // It didn't advertise itself as a base64 data image. What do you want to do?
}
```