# /teams/allMessages problems to create subscription API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to create this subscription,

I have this request:

```json
{
  "changeType": "created",
  "notificationUrl": "https://xxxx.ngrok.io/Chats",
  "resource": "/teams/allMessages",
  "expirationDateTime": "2020-09-02T20:20:46.9356913Z",
  "clientState": "clienteState",
  "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2",
  "includeResourceData": true,
  "encryptionCertificate": "{base64encodedCertificate}",
  "encryptionCertificateId": "1063858CD242BF00346FF4E35E...."
}
```

but it returns an error

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequest",
    "message": "Certificate validation error: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. ",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-09-02T20:39:41",
      "request-id": "cd73c462-3768-4283-9b6b-b7cd7a83fa0c"
    }
  }
}
```

I followed this guide to get the certificate:
"https://laurakokkarinen.com/authenticating-to-office-365-apis-with-a-certificate-step-by-step/comment-page-2/#creating-the-certificate"

I replaced characters in base 64 string.
I do not know what is my problem

Comment: Please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114044/the-input-is-not-a-valid-base-64-string-as-it-contains-a-non-base-64-character) and see if this can help.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is resolved.


I got the public key with this:
https://gist.github.com/erikbern/756b1d8df2d1487497d29b90e81f8068

or:

Go to https://portal.azure.com
Click on Azure Active Directory on the left navigation.
select my app
Select manifest then: in the json: "keyCredentials": [
{
"keyId":
"value":
}